# Yii2 custom widget assets not registering

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-extension

I'm trying to develop a custom widget, but I've run into a wall. I have some third-party JS/CSS files I need to include, but for whatever reason, Yii2 will not register them. I've followed everything in the Yii2 documentation but seem to get nowhere. My directory structure is as follows:

components
 - DildenFeedback.php
 - DildenFeedbackAsset.php
 - views/
  -- feedback.php
 - assets/
  -- feedback.min.js
  -- feedback.min.css

**DildenFeedback.php (Widget Class)**

```
<?php

namespace app\components\yii2feedbackwidget;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Widget;
use app\components\yii2feedbackwidget\DildenFeedbackAsset;

class DildenFeedback extends Widget
{

    public function run() {
        parent::run();
        DildenFeedbackAsset::register($this->view);
        return $this->render('feedback');
    }
}
```

**DildenFeedbackAsset.php (Widget Asset Class)**

```
<?php

namespace app\components\yii2feedbackwidget;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class DildenFeedbackAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $sourcePath = 'assets/';

    public $css = ['assets/feedback.min.css'];
    public $js = ['assets/feedback.min.js'];

    public $depends = ['yii\web\JqueryAsset'];
}
```

**Feedback View**

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.feedback();
</script>
```

**views/layouts/main.php** (The main template I was trying to call in)

```
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?php
    echo DildenFeedback::widget();
?>
```

So when I go to inspect the page, feedback.min.js/css are nowhere to be found. The view file is rendered correctly, but my guess is that my AssetBundle is improperly formed. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT** (From the Yii Debugger Assets):
sourcePath  /var/www/public/components/yii2feedbackwidget/assets
basePath    /var/www/public/web/assets/7e80049a
baseUrl /assets/7e80049a
css assets/feedback.min.css
js  assets/feedback.min.js
depends yii\web\JqueryAsset

**EDIT 2**
I have tested this on a fresh install of Yii2, and I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that asset folder is accessible? Do you see get error in firebug or other browser console inspector? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#using-asset-bundles

Comment: The only error that I get, is that might function $.feedback() is not valid. The JS/CSS are not shown in the sources or network (Chrome). Is there anything specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Try to activate Yii2 debug bar and see assets messages

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I didn't realize the Yii Debugger included that feature. Added it to the question.

Comment: I should make a note, that those assets are reachable via the browser. Why then, is Yii2 not seeing them?

Comment: Are these assets included in the html source by the framework?

Comment: No, they do not show up anywhere in the source code.

Comment: Try to specify $basePath and $baseUrl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95626/discussion-between-dylan-hildenbrand-and-fabrizio-caldarelli).

Comment: Show us how you call your widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, and I feel a bit silly. What it came down to, was the location of the widget call. As I noted in my original question, I was echoing the widget like so:

```
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?php
    echo DildenFeedback::widget();
?>
```

However, I did not pay attention to where that call was. It NEEDS to be before the endBody call

```
<?php
    echo DildenFeedback::widget();
?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

This ended up solving the issue. Thanks to Soju for directing me towards the widget call.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should simply correct your `sourcePath` :

```
class DildenFeedbackAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $sourcePath = '@app/components/assets/';

    public $css = ['feedback.min.css'];
    public $js = ['feedback.min.js'];

    public $depends = ['yii\web\JqueryAsset'];
}
```

You should also fix your view by using [`registerJs()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail) instead of a script tag :

```
$this->registerJs('jQuery.feedback();');
```

Comment: I was under the impression the sourcePath was supposed to be relative, which is why I had it that way. But even after trying your solution, it still isn't working. I believe this issue lies somewhere in the configuration of my app at this point. I'll try setting up a fresh install, and see where that gets me.